# Ayuda para generar JSON desde una función recursiva?

Tags: java, json, recursión

Necesito ayuda para generar este tipo de JSON desde mi función recursiva. Estoy intentando hace bastante pero no se me prende la lamparita !!

Mi JSON de salida debe tener este formato:

```
{
    "root": "/u/data/Coldview/apps",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos",
            "md5": ".........",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "folder",
                    "path": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos/lib",
                    "md5": ".........",
                    "content": [
                        {"type": "file", "name": "AMCOX.Core.jar", "md5": "........."},
                        {"type": "file", "name": "JV.Coldview.DTFtoPDF.Service.AMCOX.Compatible.jar", "md5": "........."}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "folder",
                    "path": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos/resources",
                    "md5": ".........",
                    "content": [
                        {"type": "file", "name": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos.cfg", "md5": "........."},
                        {"type": "file", "name": "ES.msg", "md5": "........."}
                    ]
                },
                {"type": "file", "name": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos.jar", "md5": "........."}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Mi función recursiva Java es la siguiente:

```
public class ComponentCompare {

    private static BufferedWriter bw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            recursive(new File("/home/incentivate/Desktop/resources")); // Directorio raíz
            File salida = new File("/home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/salida.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(salida));
//            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numDir + " directorios \n");
//            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numFiles + " archivos \n");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No existe el archivo de salida!");
        }

    } // end del main()



    public static void recursive(File dir) throws IOException {
        int numDir = 0;
        int numFiles = 0;
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray content = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject type = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject path = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject md5 = new JSONObject();

        root.put("root", dir.getAbsolutePath());

        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    // Aca va la logica del JSON
                    type.put("type", "folder");
                    path.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    content.add(i, path);
                    content.add(i, type);
                    System.out.println(root);
                    System.out.println(content);
                    System.out.println(type);
                    recursive(listFile[i]);
                    numDir++;
                } else if (listFile[i].isFile()) {
                    path.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    type.put("type", "file");
                    content.add(i, path);
                    content.add(i, type);
                    System.out.println(root);
                    System.out.println(content);
                    System.out.println(type);
                    numFiles++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(dir.toString() + " Carpetas: " + numDir + ", Archivos: " + numFiles);
        }
    } // end de recursive()

}
```

Explicación del programa:

La función recursive() recibe como parámetro una ruta a la carpeta inicial que en mi JSON debería ser

```
"root": "rutaDeLaCarpetaInicio"

"content": [

   {

    "type": si es una carpeta entonces será "folder", si es archivo será "file"

    "path": ruta de la carpeta/archivo

    "md5": a realizar luego

    "content": misma lógica de antes !!!

   }

]
```

Problemas que tengo:

Con el código publicado obtengo una salida parecida a la que deseo, pero cuando empieza a hacer la recursividad se complica todo.

El "root" me cambia de ruta cada vez que itera y los "content" se me complican para hacerlos.

No tengo mucha experiencia con JAVA y menos haciendo cosas con recursividad, si alguien me puede hechar una mano sería más que agradecida.

Saludos !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas tu elemento root lo generas cada vez que entras a tu función recursiva, por lo que no es necesario, lo recomendable en java es buscar orientación a objetos, sin embargo con tu función como la tienes lo recomendable es sacar ese atributo root y ya sea pasarlo como parámetro o hacerlo "variable global"

```
public class ComponentCompare {

    private static BufferedWriter bw;

    private static JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    private static int numDir = 0;
    private static int numFiles = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File rootDir = new File("/home/incentivate/Desktop/resources");
            root.put("root", rootDir.getAbsolutePath());
            JSONArray content = new JSONArray();
            root.put("content", content);

            recursive(rootDir, content); // Directorio raíz
            System.out.println(root);
            System.out.println(rootDir.toString() + " Carpetas: " + numDir + ", Archivos: " + numFiles);

            File salida = new File("/home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/salida.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(salida));
            //            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numDir + " directorios \n");
            //            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numFiles + " archivos \n");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No existe el archivo de salida!");
        }

    } // end del main()

    public static void recursive(File dir, JSONArray contentParent) throws IOException {

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        JSONObject md5 = new JSONObject();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                JSONObject son = new JSONObject();
                contentParent.add(son);
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    // Aca va la logica del JSON
                    son.put("type", "folder");
                    son.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    JSONArray contentSon = new JSONArray();
                    son.put("Content", contentSon);

                    recursive(listFile[i], contentSon);
                    numDir++;
                } else if (listFile[i].isFile()) {
                    son.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    son.put("type", "file");
                    numFiles++;
                }
            }
        }
    } // end de recursive()

}
```

Comment: Sos un genio, no sabes lo que me ayudaste !!! Te hago una pregunta porque no me está quedando exactamente igual a como quiero, pero muy parecido ... como hago para que quede exactamente igual a mi JSON de salida _?

Comment: estoy tocando el código pero no logro poner que cuando el listFile[i] sea una carpeta me agregue "type": "folder" ANTES del "path" ... puse esta línea pero no me funciona :(      if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    // Aca va la logica del JSON
                    obj.put("type", "folder");
                    obj.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

Comment: ya pudiste resolverlo ?

Comment: ! Gracias por tu ayuda de nuevo ... Acá me dijeron que el JSON no te garantiza el orden por lo que la solución que me pasaste está más que bien !! Ahora estoy haciendo la parte del MD5 !!! Gracias de nuevo, me reeeee ayudaste !